# Getting "HttpServletRequest" in soapMessageContext - Axis Handler

Tags: servlets, axis, soaphandler

I am trying to get "HttpServletRequest" in an AxisHandler's "handleMessage" method.
My AxisHandler implements "SOAPHandler" as seen below code..

I need to get "HttpServletRequest" in "InBoundDirection", but it returns "null".

How can I get "HttpServletRequest" in "InBoundDirection" of SOAPHandler ?

Thank you..

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext) {
    boolean direction = ((Boolean) soapMessageContext.get(SOAPMessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)).booleanValue();        
    if (direction) {
        System.out.println("direction = outbound");
    } else {
        System.out.println("direction = inbound");
        HttpServletRequest servletReq=(HttpServletRequest) soapMessageContext.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
        // BECAUSE servletReq is null the following line returns a "nullPointerException"
        System.out.println(servletReq.getRemoteHost()); 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post [jax ws getting client ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727989/jax-ws-getting-client-ip) for a very good explanation. Looks like if one wants to have a generic handler (in my case to extract the client certificate) one needs to implement the same logic for both EE container hosted webservices as well as SE hosted containers.