# How to get IP address of the calling client to the web-service application built in Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7?

Tags: java, oracle, web-services

I built a web-service application in **Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7** to be used by other clients. Simply the general steps as follow (**Server web-service Application is built ---> Deployed on server ---> Used by clients through WSDL file location**).

Now I come across a requirement where I need to get the client's **IP** address and port number.

Questions:

How to get **IP** address of the calling client to the web-service application built in Jdeveloper?

Common technologies used to built web-service applications is **AXIS** or **CXF**. What technology Jdeveloper use to built web service application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I solve the problem based on @Tomaz Solution:

[jax ws getting client ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727989/jax-ws-getting-client-ip/12816220#12816220)

In Class:

```
 @Resource WebServiceContext wsContext;
```

In Web Method:

```
MessageContext msgx = wsContext.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)msgx.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
String inCommingClientIpAddress=req.getRemoteAddr();

System.out.println("Client IP is: "+inCommingClientIpAddress
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work fine for you, it uses only the standard JAX-WS interface https://stackoverflow.com/a/12816220/1643498

I am not sure about the Web Service stack used in JDeveloper/Oracle ADF, this is most likely the WebLogic implementation of JAX-WS.